# Terraform GKE x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

Following this tutorial,
https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/gke?in=terraform/kubernetes
I have deployed a GKE cluster in GCloud.

Now when I try to schedule a deployment following this link,
https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/kubernetes-provider

It fails with,

```
kubernetes_deployment.nginx: Creating...

Error: Failed to create deployment: Post "https://<ip>/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

  on kubernetes.tf line 21, in resource "kubernetes_deployment" "nginx":
  21: resource "kubernetes_deployment" "nginx" {
```

My kubernetes.tf looks like this,

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kubernetes = {
      source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
    }
  }
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  load_config_file = false

  host     = google_container_cluster.primary.endpoint
  username = var.gke_username
  password = var.gke_password

  client_certificate     = google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.client_certificate
  client_key             = google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.client_key
  cluster_ca_certificate = google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate
}

resource "kubernetes_deployment" "nginx" {
  metadata {
    name = "scalable-nginx-example"
    labels = {
      App = "ScalableNginxExample"
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 2
    selector {
      match_labels = {
        App = "ScalableNginxExample"
      }
    }
    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          App = "ScalableNginxExample"
        }
      }
      spec {
        container {
          image = "nginx:1.7.8"
          name  = "example"

          port {
            container_port = 80
          }

          resources {
            limits {
              cpu    = "0.5"
              memory = "512Mi"
            }
            requests {
              cpu    = "250m"
              memory = "50Mi"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using MacOS to run terraform. Any help is appreciated.

Please note that kubectl get pods --all-namespaces is working fine, so I don't think it's an issue with kube config.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Is the certificate being served by `<ip>` actually signed by the CA in `certificategoogle_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate`?

Answer (score 3):

It was because the certificate was base64 encoded, changing the provider section to the below snippet, got rid of the issue.

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  load_config_file = false

  host     = google_container_cluster.primary.endpoint
  username = var.gke_username
  password = var.gke_password

  client_certificate     = base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
}
```

Comment: Do not mix problems together. Take the last part of this answer, remove and create a new question.

Comment: I removed the second half of your answer. As advised, please make new question for new issue.

Comment: Apologies, thank you for removing. I will create a new issue.